# port.ReadExisting(): Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, c++, arduino

I am building a c# application that gets information from an Arduino (button presses) and then navigates to the corresponding website in a web browser. I have 3 buttons which are respectively printing 1, 2 and 3 to the serial monitor.

Following that, when a software button is pressed, the c# app reads the number that has been sent by the arduino using port(ReadExisting()) with port being the name of my serial port.

It works well when I press an Arduino button, my application reads the number and performs the correct action. However, I tried printing a number to the serial monitor when no button is pressed (I tried both 0 and 4) but it doesn't seem to work. The serial monitor on Arduino does show the number appearing when none of the buttons is pressed, but my c# crashes when attempting to read it.

The error message I get when it crashes is "input string was not in a correct format"

The relevant bit of the c# code (the text is in Dutch but it is not important):

```
 private void updateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            message = Convert.ToInt32(port.ReadExisting());
            btnLab.Text = Convert.ToString(message);

            if (message == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Er is drugsafval gedropt in Breda! Klik op alarm voor de locatie en op route voor de weg ernaartoe.");
                logBox.Items.Add("Merodelaan Breda," + DateTime.Now);
            } else if (message == 2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Er is drugsafval gedropt in Tilburg! Klik op alarm voor de locatie en op route voor de weg ernaartoe.");
                logBox.Items.Add("Leijweg Tilburg," + DateTime.Now);
            } else if (message == 3)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Er is drugsafval gedropt in Breda! Klik op alarm voor de locatie en op route voor de weg ernaartoe.");
                logBox.Items.Add("Bergsche Hoevenpad Oss," + DateTime.Now);
            } 
        } else if (message == 0)
        {
                MessageBox.Show("Er is momenteel geen alarm.");

}
```

Relevant corresponding Arduino code (for one of the buttons, for each next button it is completely the same):

```
void loop() {
  String input = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
  bredaState = digitalRead(bredaBtn);
  tilburgState = digitalRead(tilburgBtn);
  ossState = digitalRead(ossBtn);

  if (bredaState == LOW)
  {
    digitalWrite(bredaLed, LOW);
    Serial.println("0");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("1");
    lcd.clear();

    lcd.print("Alarm:Drugsafval");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("in Breda!");
    bredaState = digitalRead(bredaBtn);
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    digitalWrite(bredaLed, HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(bredaLed, LOW);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(bredaLed, HIGH);
    }

    buzz();
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Er is momenteel");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("geen alarm!");
  }
```

Comment: `port.ReadExisting()` is not returning an integer. Assign it to a variable before calling `Convert.ToInt32` to see what its value is.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the input first, and then use int.TryParse so that an error is not thrown if it fails. You may also want to do some additional validation on the value returned from port.ReadExisting() first. The below code should stop the error from happening.

```
var input = port.ReadExisting();
int message;
if (int.TryParse(input, out message))
{
    btnLab.Text = Convert.ToString(message);
    if (message == 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Er is drugsafval gedropt in Breda! Klik op alarm voor de locatie en op route voor de weg ernaartoe.");
        logBox.Items.Add("Merodelaan Breda," + DateTime.Now);
    }
    else if (message == 2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Er is drugsafval gedropt in Tilburg! Klik op alarm voor de locatie en op route voor de weg ernaartoe.");
        logBox.Items.Add("Leijweg Tilburg," + DateTime.Now);
    }
    else if (message == 3)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Er is drugsafval gedropt in Breda! Klik op alarm voor de locatie en op route voor de weg ernaartoe.");
        logBox.Items.Add("Bergsche Hoevenpad Oss," + DateTime.Now);
    }
    else if (message == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Er is momenteel geen alarm.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also perform a [ReadChar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readchar?view=netframework-4.8) followed by a [Switch-Statement](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_switch_statement.htm)

```
uint8_t input = (uint8_t)port.ReadChar();
switch(input)
{
   case '1': 
       MessageBox.Show("Er is drugsafval gedropt in Breda! Klik op alarm voor de locatie en op route voor de weg ernaartoe.");
       logBox.Items.Add("Merodelaan Breda," + DateTime.Now);
       break;
  //etc...
  case '0':
      MessageBox.Show("Er is momenteel geen alarm.");
      break;
  default: //an unknown value
      break; //do nothing
}
```